# Replace the entire expression based on a partial match in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a factor variable. I want to search for a pattern and replace all of the results that contain at least a partial match.

```
clrs <- c("blue", "light blue", "red", "rose", "ruby", "yellow", "green", "black", "brown", "royal blue")
dfx <- data.frame(colors=clrs, Amount=sample(100,10))
dfx

       colors Amount
1        blue     23
2  light blue     95
3         red     45
4        rose     46
5        ruby     63
6      yellow      9
7       green     33
8       black     62
9       brown     34
10 royal blue     18
```

In this example I want to find all off the records that contain the word blue in the colors variable and replace the entire contents with "Blue".

So my results should look like this...

```
       colors Amount
1        Blue     23
2        Blue     95
3         red     45
4        rose     46
5        ruby     63
6      yellow      9
7       green     33
8       black     62
9       brown     34
10       Blue     18
```

I've used grep to find the ones I want to replace

```
grep("blue", dfx$colors, value = TRUE)

[1] "blue"       "light blue" "royal blue"
```

I've tried using gsub:

```
gsub("blue", "Blue", dfx$colors)
```

But that doesn't change anything.

I've tried other posts on this site with similar questions including this one...

[R - Replace entire strings based on partial match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418864/r-replace-entire-strings-based-on-partial-match)

But none of the answers seem to be working.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would say that this is a different question because that example is not a data frame and the answer given does not work when applied to a data frame. I had already tried that answer and got the following results: > dfx$colors[grepl("Blue", dfx$colors)] <- "Blue"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, grepl("Blue", dfx$colors), value = c(NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
This change all of my blues to NAs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the very first answer from the question you linked to. Just use

```
dfx$colors[grepl("blue", dfx$colors)] <- "Blue"
```

Use `grepl` to return a TRUE/FALSE value for each element in the vector.

Also, make sure your column is a character variable and not a factor first

```
dfx$colors < - as.character(dfx$colors)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I worked after changing the variable to character. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without changing the variable class? Thanks.

Comment: well, the problem in the example was that "Blue" wasn't an existing factor level. Adding new levels in this way is not trivial in base R. better to just do the conversion as characters and convert back to factor if needed afterward.