# Replace entire strings in column based on partial match in other column

Tags: r, text, tibble, grepl, mutate

my issue is similar to this one here ([Replace entire strings based on partial match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418864/replace-entire-strings-based-on-partial-match)) or this ([Replace the entire expression based on a partial match in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209842/replace-the-entire-expression-based-on-a-partial-match-in-r))

I think I have a tibble? that is something like this

My tibble
[image]
I tried to use code similar to that of the linked post to change the text in one column based on a partial match in another. it isn't quite working.

```
free <- c("journal & radius wear damage","residual magnetism","damaged wheel","gouge in edge","wheel seat")

f2 <- tibble(free)
f2 %>%
  mutate(catag = "Uncategorised") %>%
print(f2)
#classify if contains text 'barrel'
f2$catag[grepl("wheel", f2$free)] <- "Wheel related issue"

print(f2)
```

it found all my matches that contained 'wheel' and changed the 'catag' column to 'wheel related issue' but then made all the other column entries 'na'

not quite right
[image]

Is there a way to only change the ones that match and leave the ones that don't. I think it is an issue with `mutate` but this was a way I found to add a column with a constant value.

I tried looking for a solution, but just kept ending up at the same posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full [*tidyverse*](https://www.tidyverse.org/) solution using `mutate()`, `case_when()` and `str_detect()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

free <- c('journal & radius wear damage',
          'residual magnetism',
          'damaged wheel',
          'gouge in edge',
          'wheel seat')

# create tibble:
f2 <- tibble(free)

# conditionally set 'catag':
f2 |>
  mutate(catag = case_when(str_detect(free, 'wheel') ~ 'Wheel related issue',
                           T ~ 'Uncategorised'))
```

[`if_else()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html) is also a possible solution, but doesn't allow for multiple conditions to be evaluated.

Comment: I like this because I think I can add more conditions. I still don't understand why the 'na' replaced the 'uncategorised')

Comment: That's right, `case_when()` can take multiple conditions. There shouldn't be any NA values using the above solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ifelse` to conditionally change the values.

```
f2 <- transform(f2, catag = ifelse(grepl("wheel", free), 
                        "Wheel related issue", "Uncategorised"))
f2

#                       free               catag
#1 journal & radius wear damage       Uncategorised
#2           residual magnetism       Uncategorised
#3                damaged wheel Wheel related issue
#4                gouge in edge       Uncategorised
#5                   wheel seat Wheel related issue
```

Similarly, using `dplyr` functions :

```
library(dplyr)

f2 %>%
  mutate(catag = if_else(grepl("wheel", free), 
                         "Wheel related issue", "Uncategorised"))
```

**data**

```
f2 <- tibble(free = c("journal & radius wear damage","residual magnetism",
                       "damaged wheel","gouge in edge","wheel seat"))
```